# Redirect from Facebook to IOS application's particular post

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, deep-linking

Hi I am trying to achieve a redirect from facebook to my app. In my scenario I post a photo from my application to facebook. Just like instagram. Now what I want is From facebook app I need to see the link like "open this in MyApp" just like instagram does..  Here is my code

```
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:imageName];    
SBJSON *jsonWriter=[SBJSON new]; 

NSArray *actionlinks=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"MyApp",@"name",@"https://apps.facebook.com/abskdjk/",@"link", nil], nil];

actionlinks=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"MyApp",@"name",@"https://m.facebook.com/apps/abskdjk/",@"link", nil], nil];
NSString *actionLinkStr=[jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionlinks];

NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://apps.facebook.com/abskdjk"];

NSMutableDictionary *params2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"507124573",@"app_id",
                                @"This is myApp", @"caption",
                                urlString, @"link",

                                UIImagePNGRepresentation(image), @"picture",

                                actionLinkStr, @"actions",
                               nil];  

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:params2 HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
{
    if (!error) {
         NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
    }
    else {        
         NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
    }


}];
```

This code does post the photo on facebook but does not show an option to open that particular photo in My app or in other words it does not allow me to redirect to my app just like instagram. How can I redirect from a photo to my app like instagram?

Comment: There's currently no supported way to do this.

Comment: How other apps are doing it ?

Comment: What other apps are doing it aside from Instagram (which FB owns)?

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work you have to use Facebook Deep Linking.

There is an [extensive documentation on the FB website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios) on how to do this